commands in the .bat file
there is a /min command that runs the file .exe is in minimized mode. how to make this one .exe was running in the background and was not displayed in the taskbar.which command should I use?
enter image description here
the image shows how it works. what needs to be fixed here to get what I want?
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
:: 65001 - UTF-8

cd /d "%~dp0"

set BIN=%~dp0bin\

start "zapret: general" /min"%BIN%winws.exe" --wf-raw="@rules.txt" ^
--filter-udp=443 --hostlist="list-general.txt" --dpi-desync=fake --dpi-desync-repeats=6 --dpi-desync-fake-quic="%BIN%quic_initial_www_google_com.bin" --new ^
--filter-udp=50000-65535 --dpi-desync=fake --dpi-desync-any-protocol --dpi-desync-cutoff=d3 --dpi-desync-repeats=6 --dpi-desync-fake-quic="%BIN%quic_initial_www_google_com.bin" --new ^
--filter-tcp=80 --hostlist="list-general.txt" --dpi-desync=fake,split2 --dpi-desync-autottl=2 --dpi-desync-fooling=md5sig --new ^
--filter-tcp=443 --hostlist="list-general.txt" --dpi-desync=fake,split --dpi-desync-autottl=2 --dpi-desync-repeats=6 --dpi-desync-fooling=badseq --dpi-desync-fake-tls="%BIN%tls_clienthello_www_google_com.bin"

